# How to save question before going back to the same question in Google Forms?

Tags: google-forms

I need to make a questionnaire. The idea of the questionnaire is that it asks the user first two different questions (name and country) and after the two questions it asks that if the user wants to put some other name and country to the questionnaire. If not it goes to next questions but if yes it should save the name and country that the user has already put and then go back to the first to questions so that the user could add new ones. Is it possible to do? Of course it is possible to go back to first questions but it leaves the answers there and doesn't save the answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Google Forms. One alternative is to create sections asking for name and country questions and include multiple option question asking if they want to add another name and question. Set this question No option to submit the form and the Yes option to go to the next question.

Answer (score 0):

There 's an new option in the setting added from a while allowing to autosave, as if it's a google document. Try it, and then the user can be back to the form & find the data not wiped even if he refreshes the page.

[image]